# Azure B2C custom policy passwordless signin schema validation error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure B2C custom policy for passwordless signin following this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email).

The <***BuildingBlocks***> section has the <***ClaimsTransformations***>.....</***ClaimsTransformations***> which defines random password generation. To customize the UI for my login screens I have also added <***ContentDefinitions***> .... </***ContentDefinitions***> inside <***BuildingBlocks***> section.

Now I am getting a validation error when trying to upload the *TrustFrameworkExtensions_passwordless_only.xml* file saying  that the ---> ***element <***BuildingBlocks***> has invalid child element <***ClaimsTransformations***>. List of possible elements expected: Localisation, DisplayControls***.

This is strange because in the reference schema ClaimsTransformations is also a valid element. Not idea why I am getting this error. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you putting the `ContentDefinitions` block before `ClaimsTransformations` block? The order matters so please try to follow the order in this [ADB2C official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks) and see if it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input @ray the order of the elements was the issue I was facing. Moving ClaimsTransformations to the top and then putting ContentDefinitions solved the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official AD B2C custom policy documentation on [BuildingBlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks):

> The BuildingBlocks element contains the following elements that must be specified in the order defined:

```
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      ...
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <Predicates>
    ...
    </Predicates>
    <PredicateValidations>
    ...
    </PredicateValidations>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      ...
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      ...
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization>
      ...
    </Localization>
    <DisplayControls>
      ...
    </DisplayControls>
 </BuildingBlocks>
```

So the order matters and you need to place `ContentDefinitions` block after `ClaimsTransformations` block.